# Nowhere Differentiable function over a non-compact space

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

As far as I have studied analysis it is very hard to study the nowhere differentiable functions. And the function looks very bad as it have non differentiability at each point of its domain. If these type of functions are defined over a compact space then we have a nice theorem over that i.e

> Most of the functions are nowhere differentiable.

But as I have searched over the Internet I haven't found anything about the functions which are defined over non compact spaces. Moreover in the compact spaces, we can use Weierstrass Approximation Theorem over the nowhere differentiable function defined on a compact space to give it a good approximation by the Bernstein Polynomials. My query was is it possible to have such approximation for the nowhere differentiable function defined over non compact space. Again we know that polynomials are everywhere differentiable in $\Bbb R$ so in case of the nowhere differentiable function defined on a compact space we'll get a sequence of everywhere differentiable functions defined converging to that nowhere differentiable function. But I can't find anything about the functions defined over non compact space.

Comment: What is your definition of "differentiable approximation"?

Comment: Every partial sum of terms of the Weierstrass function is differentiable.

Comment: I mean if we take a sequence of Nowhere differentiable function over a Non Compact Space will it converge to a function which is differentiable atleast at countably many points

Comment: Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be continuous and bounded and nowhere differentiable.   For $n\in \Bbb N$ and $x\in \Bbb R$  let $f_n(x)=f(x)+1/n$ and $g_n(x)=f(x)/n$......  Each $ f_n$  and each  $g_n$  is continuous but nowhere differentiable and  $(f_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f.$  while $(g_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to  $0.$

Comment: You are talking about a particular sequence but what I am trying to say is is it possible to approximate a no Where differentiable function to a function which is differentiable atleast at countably many points

Comment: Like if fn is a Cauchy sequence of Nowhere differentiable function defined over non compact space then how will the limiting function look??Will it be differentiable atleast at countably many points or something else.Just like Form Weistrass Approximation Theorem We can say if We define the same sequence over a compact space then it'll give us a sequence of sequence of polynomials all of which are everywhere differentiable

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ)

Comment: Please understand the merit of the question sir if you Don't get a sequence how will you approximate the function!!!

Comment: Why the question is irrelevant!!Will you please elaborate??

Comment: The problem is not that your question is irrelevant. The problem is that it is hard to understand what your are asking. Please consider adding more details via an [edit]

Comment: Now the question is put on hold and in order to get an answer you should update the question to make it clear what you're asking. You should do this by editing the question (clarifications in comments don't count). Besides your clarifications are somewhat confusing. In other words you should think through exactly what you mean by "differentiable approximation" and specify that in the question.

Comment: As suggested I have changed my question with respect to your response now I hope it's clear

Comment: Weierstrass doesn't prove anything about Bernstein. They are different approaches to the same conclusion.

Comment: Yes sir!!!I agree!!What I want to tell is We can approximate the Nowhere differentiable function defined over the compact space using Bernstein Polynomial or Weistrass Approximation Theorem they are the same thing!!But what is about the non compact space??Is such approximation possible there??

Comment: You can uniformly approximate any continuous function on $\mathbb R$ by smooth functions.

Comment: Sir please elaborate since I am not that much expert on analysis since I am only an undergraduate student

Answer (score 0):

The problem with non-compact domain is that it will allow the function to "misbehave" in a way that a polynomial can't approximate well in some senses. Take for example $f(x) = e^x + W(x)$ where $W$ is the Weierstrass function this increases exponentially which a polynomial can't keep up with. The difference to a polynomial will always be unbounded.

However you can create a sequence of polynomials that converge to the function pointwise since you according to WAT can find a polynomial $p_n$ such that $|f(x)-p_n(x)|<2^{-n}$ for all $|x|\le N$. This sequence will converge pointwise (it will also converge uniformly on any compact subset, which sometimes can be useful property).

If you don't require the function to be polynomial you can get uniform convergence.